# racket-error-application: not a procedure;

Tags: racket

```
(define (matcherbot-creator pattern)
    (lambda (sent) 
        (cond ( (if (memsent? pattern sent) 
                        (outfollow pattern sent)
                        #f)
              ((endofsent? pattern sent) '())
              ((empty? pattern) sent)))
  ))

(define (memsent? pattern sent)
    (cond ((empty? pattern) #t)
          ((empty? sent) #f)
          ((equal? (first pattern) (first sent))
           (memsent? (bf pattern) (bf sent)))
           (else (memsent? pattern (bf sent)))))

(define (outfollow pattern sent)
    (cond ((empty? sent) '())
          ((empty? pattern) 'sent) 
          ((equal? (first pattern) (first sent))
            (se '() (outfollow (bf pattern) (bf sent))))
          (else (outfollow pattern (bf sent)))
    ))

(define (endofsent? pattern sent) 
    (cond ((empty? sent) #t)
          ((empty? pattern) sent)
          ((equal? (first pattern) (first sent))
           (endofsent? (bf pattern) (bf sent)))
        (else (endofsent? pattern (bf sent)))))
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: The program above doesn't run due to `bf` being undefined. @jason Do you have a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `math/bigfloat` library with `(require math/bigfloat)`